# Plot Histograms with bars each one with a constant pass (For example, each 0.5 metres)

Tags: python

If i have data=[0.1,0.6,2.0,2.0,6.2,1.0,1.6,1.8] data in metres

I want to do a histogram grouping the data in intervals of 0.5 metres (that is in intervals of 0-0.5,0.5-1,1-1.5,1.5-2...) I don't want to define the number of bras (number of bins), i wants to define the weith of the interval.

Thank for your help

Comment: weith no, WIDHT!!

Comment: Do you know that you can edit your post using the `Edit` linke below your question?

Answer (score 1):

the range function does not work for numbers with decimals, however, if you use only one decimal you can multiply everything by ten and then divide.
As for example here

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0.1,0.6,2.0,2.0,6.2,1.0,1.6,1.8] 
data_multiply=[int(i*10) for i in data]

binwidth=int(0.5*10)

plt.hist(data, bins=[i/10 for i in range(0,max(data_multiply)+binwidth, binwidth)])
plt.show()
```

Another option is to import numpy that if it has a range function that works with floats

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = [0.1,0.6,2.0,2.0,6.2,1.0,1.6,1.8] 
binwidth=0.5
plt.hist(data, bins=list(np.arange(0, max(data)+binwidth, binwidth)))
plt.show()
```